# Positioning image in the page with OnMouseOver function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that onmouseover load a javascript function which is

```
function imgEnlarge(val) {
    var imageFile = getVal(arrayFile, {
        'id': val
    }, 'picture');
    var imagePath = 'admin/img/' + imageFile;
    document.getElementById("imgDisplay").innerHTML = '<img src="' + imagePath + '" style="width:800px;height600px">';
} //end enlarge function


.imgDisplay {
    top: 50;
    left: 200;
    position: absolute;
    z - index: 999;
    width: 600 px;
    height: 500 px;
}
```

The problem is when i scroll down to e.g middle of the page, the display is still at the "top of the page" as I can see the bottom of the image appearing on the div.

I have an empty div at the top of my site that is having the id of imgDisplay

How do I fix the code such that onmouseover, the picture display will at the current screen X,Y instead of top: and left: (from the top of page)

Comment: Please indent your code!  http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Try `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set the position of your image as fixed and top and left properties to 0.

Here is a javascript solution:

```
 var image = document.getElementById('imgDisplay');

    image.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        this.style.position = "fixed";
        this.style.top = 0;
        this.style.left = 0;
    });
```